# Container Startup Failure after Stopping: Red Hat Single Sign-On Docker Image (7.6-25)

Tags: docker, single-sign-on, keycloak, redhat

When attempting to run the Red Hat Single Sign-On (RH SSO) Docker image with the tag 7.6-25 (registry.redhat.io/rh-sso-7/sso76-openshift-rhel8:7.6-25), an issue has been observed where the container fails to start up properly after it has been stopped once.

After the initial run of the container, the RH SSO application starts as expected, and services become available. However, upon stopping the container, subsequent attempts to start it result in immediate failure. The container initiates startup but quickly exits, preventing the application from being accessible.

The logs don't indicate any specific error, however when I tried to reproduce the error using version 7.6-10, I got this error.

```
2023-08-30 02:04:18 00:04:18,093 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
2023-08-30 02:04:18     ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
2023-08-30 02:04:18     ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS")
2023-08-30 02:04:18 ]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [
2023-08-30 02:04:18     (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
2023-08-30 02:04:18     (\"data-source\" => \"KeycloakDS\")
2023-08-30 02:04:18 ]"
2023-08-30 02:04:18 00:04:18,210 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) "WFLYCTL0193: Failed executing subsystem datasources boot operations"
2023-08-30 02:04:18 00:04:18,212 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("parallel-subsystem-boot") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: "\"WFLYCTL0193: Failed executing subsystem datasources boot operations\""
2023-08-30 02:04:18 00:04:18,218 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

EDIT: docker compose config

```
  rh-sso:
    container_name: rh-sso
    image: registry.redhat.io/rh-sso-7/sso76-openshift-rhel8:7.6-25
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" 
    environment:
      SSO_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      SSO_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
```

Steps to Reproduce:

1- Start the RH SSO Docker container with the command:
`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 registry.redhat.io/rh-sso-7/sso76-openshift-rhel8:7.6-25`

2- Access the application and ensure it's working as expected.

3- Stop the container using the following command or through Docker Desktop/Compose:
`docker stop <container_id>`

4- Attempt to start the container again with the same command used in Step 1.

5- Observe that the container exits immediately without the application becoming accessible.

Comment: Do previous versions do the same thing? That sounds like a bug.

There's a file within the image that's being modified somehow to add the duplicate data source definition, but unless you really intended to add a second data source that is probably not your fault.

Comment: The docker compose config I'm using is pretty simple I don't think I'm adding any data source, and yes i tried other previous versions i get the same behavior, I found the same bug with older versions of keycloak images but the latest one doesn't have this issue.

Comment: So using latest version fixed the issue?

Comment: The keycloak image's latest version doesn’t have this issue , unlike the red hat sso 7.6 image thst i want to use.